# how to perform right join on sql query if i have a relation table for 2 master table and want to show all records from both master tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables. Table A and Table B. Both are connected with a many-to-many relationship.

**Table A:**

```
ID
---
1
2
3
```

**Table B:**

```
ID    
---    
3    
4    
5
```

**Table AB:**

```
ID | A_ID | B_ID
----------------
5  | 1    | 4
6  | 1    | 3
7  | 2    | 3
```

Now What I need as my results  it is like below

```
 A_ID | B_ID | Relation_Id 
--------------------------
 1    | 3    |   6
 1    | 4    |   5
 1    | 5    |   Null
 2    | 3    |   7
 2    | 4    |  Null
 2    | 5    |  Null
```

and so on  I need all records from table A then table B and in the last column if they have relation then id otherwise null.

Any help will be great..........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a `CROSS JOIN` between `TableA` and `TableB` so as to get *all possible combinations* (aka cartesian product).

Then perform a `LEFT JOIN` to `TableAB` to find if a relation really exists:

```
SELECT a.ID AS A_ID, b.ID AS B_ID, ab.ID AS Relation_Id 
FROM TableA AS a
CROSS JOIN TableB AS b
LEFT JOIN TableAB AS ab ON a.ID = ab.A_ID AND b.ID = ab.B_ID
ORDER BY A_ID, B_ID
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b9b07/2)

Comment: but its results 8 rows. Expected output have only 6 rows

Comment: @bmsqldev I don't think so. After expected result set OP states *... and so on*. In subject stands: *want to show all records from both master tables*. These are *separate* tables with *many-to-many* relationship. Hence, the OP is looking after *all possible combinations*.

Comment: perfect @Bestos that's what I need